# Can you get a value of a variable by a the name in a string?

Tags: php

I have this array in my method:

```
$requiredFields = array("username", "email", "password");
```

In my parameters I ask for some standard register fields. I want make an if statement where I can check if the required fields are filled in.

The way I want to do this was by was getting the value of an array and get the parameter by that value.

Is this even possible? Or do I have to do it on a different way?

**EDIT:** The parameters comes in as indiviudal variables, not in an array.

Comment: Can't find a great duplicate at the moment, which surely exists, so I'll just link you to the manual: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Comment: @deceze This is quite usefull, cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<?
foreach ($requiredFields as $field) {
  if (trim($_POST[$field]) == '') {
    echo 'Field '.$field.' should not be empty!<br>';
  }
}
```

Comment: @ThisGuy `is_empty`? You mean, `empty`? And if so, all those other checks are redundant.

Comment: @ThisGuy [The Definitive Guide To PHP's isset And empty](http://kunststube.net/isset/)

Comment: $requiredFields = array("username", "email", "password");
foreach ($requiredFields as $field) {
  $postData = ['username' => 'abcd', 'email' => 'a@gmail.com'];
  if (!isset(trim($postData[$field])) && empty(trim($postData[$field]))) {
    echo 'Field '.$field.' should not be empty!<br>';
  }
}

Comment: @Krishna *"If __not__ set __and__ empty"*…?!